# How to add new dataset in line chart of chart.js by iterating over dictionary in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to display linechart from charts.js where it shows the pass,fail and skipped test case reults in graph. Here i have hardcoded the number of data in a dataset. I want to add the datapoints by iterating through the object.
Object looks like this

```
var temp = {"2020":[1,2,3],
            "2021":[4,5,6]}
```

And my javascript function for line chart below.

```
    function GetHealthReport(health,id) {
    console.log(health);
    var Date = Object.keys(health);

    var ctxL = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: Date,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label:"Pass",
                data: [health[Date[0]][0],health[Date[1]][0],health[Date[2]][0],health[Date[3]][0],health[Date[4]][0]],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(71,193,28,0.71)'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label:"Failed",
                    data: [health[Date[0]][1],health[Date[1]][1],health[Date[2]][1],health[Date[3]][1],health[Date[4]][1]],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(212,0,13,0.71)'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label:"Skipped",
                    data: [health[Date[0]][2],health[Date[1]][2],health[Date[2]][2],health[Date[3]][2],health[Date[4]][2]],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(228,78,231,0.56)'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data is available in the variable `health`, you can extract the `labels` through [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as follows.

```
labels: Object.keys(health),
```

The `data` of individual datasets can be extracted through [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), followed by [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The data of the first dataset for example is defined as follows.

```
data: Object.values(health).map(v => v[0]),
```

Please have a look at your amended and runnable code below.

```js
const health = {
  "2020": [1, 2, 3],
  "2021": [4, 5, 6]
}

var myLineChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: Object.keys(health),
    datasets: [{
        label: "Pass",
        data: Object.values(health).map(v => v[0]),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(71,193,28, 0.71)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(71,193,28)',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: "Failed",
        data: Object.values(health).map(v => v[1]),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(212,0,13,0.71)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(212,0,13)',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: "Skipped",
        data: Object.values(health).map(v => v[2]),
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(228,78,231,0.56)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(228,78,231)',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```